# Insert Data By Splitting Column into Different Rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temporary table
[Temporary Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN9js.png)

| ID | Code | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A001 | A, B |
| 2 | B001 | A, B |
| 3 | C001 | A, B |

& a source table in my database
[Source Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPIRH.png)

| ID | Code | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A001 | Text A |
| 2 | B001 | Text B |
| 3 | C001 | Text C |

I want to insert the the 'type' data to have output like this.
Data types of 'type' is char(20).
[Output Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KJGZ.png)

| ID | Code | Text | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A001 | Text A | A |
| 2 | A001 | Text A | B |
| 3 | B001 | Text B | A |
| 4 | B001 | Text B | B |
| 5 | C001 | Text C | A |
| 6 | C001 | Text C | B |

Is it possible to come out the output by using pure SQL query?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. You can use `JOIN` and `APPLY` with [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desired result using `ROW_NUMBER` for the id column and `STRING_SPLIT` to separate the values from "A,B" into A and B.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.code) AS id,
t1.code, t2.text, sp.value AS type 
FROM table1 AS t1 
OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t1.type, ',') sp
JOIN table2 AS t2 
ON t1.code = t2.code;
```

You can replicate this here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=602914d8e83eea89987567f727a44904)

I recommend to rename the columns "type" and "text" if possible since SQL key words should not be used as column name or table name.